# Regex - delete all lines which does not match pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a following string (with newlines):

```
<a>something1</a>
<a>something2</a>
<a>something3</a>
```

I need to match something2 and something3 and replace it, but then I have a result:

```
<a>something1</a>
<a>replacement2</a>
<a>replacement3</a>
```

but I need to have only replacements, with no something1. There are 3000 strings like that, so deleting it myself would take a lot of time. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you needing to replace between `<a>` and `</a>` or the whole line?

Comment: hey:) I needed to replace between, everything is ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`preg_filter` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php)** to do filtering and replacement in one go:

```
$s = <<< EOF
<a>something1</a>
<a>something2</a>
<a>something3</a>
EOF;

$subject = explode("\n", $s); 
echo implode("\n", preg_filter('~\bsomething([02-9])\b~', 'replacement$1', $subject));
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<a>replacement2</a>
<a>replacement3</a>
```

Comment: hey, I liked your answer, unfortunately I dont have 15 points, so I write +1 in comment:)

Comment: No issue @jakub: It is good enough to accept the answer but you have 15 reps now :)

Comment: yeah :) so +1 for you;)